# I am trying to send a encoded message data(application/x-www-form-urlencoded) to my Restsharp request but i am getting a bad request error message

Tags: restsharp, xunit

My Request Method: Post

```
Content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
using  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(RequestBody);
```

I have an issue here as i am converting my Json Body to UrlEncode for that reason i am sending as a sting to my RestSharp request as shown below.

```
\\Request Model
public class Request
    { 
        public string MessageId { get; set; }
        public bool IsOffline { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public string MessageType { get; set; }
    }
```

```
\\xUnit 
[Fact]
        public void Login()
        {

            Request request = new Request
            {
                MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                MessageType = "KioskLogin",
                IsOffline = false,
                LanguageCode = "en"
            };
            String RequestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

            //url encode the json
            var payload = String.Format("payload={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(RequestBody));

            IRestResponse response = _restServices.PostRequest(payload);

            Response parsedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response.Content);

            response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

```
\\I Builded this RestSharp code Like
    public IRestResponse PostRequest(String Request)
        {
            var restClient = new RestClient(ConfigurationReader.Get("Environment:QA:Endpoint"));
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddJsonBody(payload);

            IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute(request);
            return response;
        }
```

I am able to send the request in URLEncoded form using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(RequestBody)` but i have a issue here in my request i am seeing like 
`"payload=%7B%0A%22MessageId%22%3A%20%222e55dcdf-d877-4970-870e-fef841aff9a1%22%2C%0A%09%22MessageType%22%3A%20%22Login%22%2C%0A%22IsOffline%22%3A%20false%2C%0A%09%22LanguageCode%22%3A%20%22es%22%0A%7D"`

But i don't need that to be in " " i need that to be like this
`payload=%7B%0A%22MessageId%22%3A%20%222e55dcdf-d877-4970-870e-fef841aff9a1%22%2C%0A%09%22MessageType%22%3A%20%22Login%22%2C%0A%22IsOffline%22%3A%20false%2C%0A%09%22LanguageCode%22%3A%20%22es%22%0A%7D`
If it is like this then i will get the response correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting success response when I send my request body in `request.AddParameter("Payload", payload, ParameterType.RequestBody);` insted of sending in `request.AddJsonBody(payload);`.